# std::list push_back unrelated types

Tags: c++, list, push-back

Is it possible to push_back to a list of userClass a variable with different type?

```
list<MyClass*>* myList
list<int>* NewData

// -- ..some population of NewDat.. --

myList->push_back(NewData);
```

Comment: plz run the code you intended to write, then update your answer with full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What you are asking for is not possible. `myList` stores `MyClass*`s, not `int`s or lists of `int`s. If you want a generic list, you can use `std::list<std::any>`, or, in case you know the types in advance, `std::list<std::variant<(types here)>>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible for vector or list to hold multiple types of data.